# Is it possible to use the SELECT INTO clause with UNION [ALL]?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server this inserts 100 records, from the Customers table into tmpFerdeen  :-

```
SELECT top(100)*
INTO tmpFerdeen
FROM Customers
```

Is it possible to do a SELECT INTO across a UNION ALL SELECT :-

```
SELECT top(100)* 
FROM Customers
UNION All
SELECT top(100)* 
FROM CustomerEurope
UNION All
SELECT top(100)* 
FROM CustomerAsia
UNION All
SELECT top(100)* 
FROM CustomerAmericas
```

Not too sure where to add the INTO clause.

Comment: Are you sure you need the union all?

Comment: Yes. As records are unique accross all tables.

Answer (score 276, accepted):

This works in SQL Server:

```
SELECT * INTO tmpFerdeen FROM (
  SELECT top 100 * 
  FROM Customers
  UNION All
  SELECT top 100 * 
  FROM CustomerEurope
  UNION All
  SELECT top 100 * 
  FROM CustomerAsia
  UNION All
  SELECT top 100 * 
  FROM CustomerAmericas
) as tmp
```

Comment: Also this works SELECT top 100 * INTO tmpFerdeen FROM Customers  UNION All  SELECT top 100 *   FROM CustomerEurope  UNION All  SELECT top 100 *   FROM CustomerAsia  UNION All  SELECT top 100 *   FROM CustomerAmericas (sorry can't format the sql here). Thanks!

Comment: What is the significance of "as tmp"?

Comment: @chrisVanOpstal, why have you selected top 100? When we select all records it gives error as- "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.
". Please give some solution.

Comment: Hi about what @Dave asked, I see that removing the "as tmp" results in a error "Incorrect syntax expecting as, id, or quoted_id". So what is it used for?

Comment: @Dave, petric: in SQL Server, temporary tables need to be given a name. That's all. The tmp doesn't serve any other function other than making the SQL statement a valid one. On Oracle SQL, for example, this is optional.

Comment: @Dave: The potential use would be in more complex queries, where you wish to reference certain columns out of this sub-query.

Answer (score 157):

You don't need a derived table at all for this.

Just put the `INTO` after the first `SELECT`

```
SELECT top(100)* 
INTO tmpFerdeen
FROM Customers
UNION All
SELECT top(100)* 
FROM CustomerEurope
UNION All
SELECT top(100)* 
FROM CustomerAsia
UNION All
SELECT top(100)* 
FROM CustomerAmericas
```

Comment: I disagree - whilst the above answer is also correct, the accepted answer is clearer in it's intention

Comment: @endurium - I disagree with your disagreement. If you know what the syntax does (something you only need to learn once) it is perfectly clear

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT * INTO tmpFerdeen FROM 
(SELECT top(100)*  
FROM Customers 
UNION All 
SELECT top(100)*  
FROM CustomerEurope 
UNION All 
SELECT top(100)*  
FROM CustomerAsia 
UNION All 
SELECT top(100)*  
FROM CustomerAmericas) AS Blablabal
```

This "Blablabal" is necessary

Answer (score 1):

For MS Access queries, this worked:

```
SELECT * INTO tmpFerdeen FROM( 
    SELECT top(100) *
    FROM Customers 
UNION All 
    SELECT top(100) *  
    FROM CustomerEurope 
UNION All 
    SELECT top(100) *  
    FROM CustomerAsia 
UNION All 
    SELECT top(100) *  
    FROM CustomerAmericas
)
```

This did NOT work in MS Access

```
SELECT top(100) * 
  INTO tmpFerdeen
  FROM Customers
UNION All
  SELECT top(100) * 
  FROM CustomerEurope
UNION All
  SELECT top(100) * 
  FROM CustomerAsia
UNION All
  SELECT top(100) * 
  FROM CustomerAmericas
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
SELECT top(100)* into #tmpFerdeen
FROM Customers

Insert into #tmpFerdeen
SELECT top(100)* 
FROM CustomerEurope

Insert into #tmpFerdeen
SELECT top(100)* 
FROM CustomerAsia

Insert into #tmpFerdeen
SELECT top(100)* 
FROM CustomerAmericas
```

Answer (score 1):

The challenge I see with the solution:

```
FROM( 
SELECT top(100) *
    FROM Customers 
UNION
    SELECT top(100) *  
    FROM CustomerEurope 
UNION 
    SELECT top(100) *  
    FROM CustomerAsia 
UNION
    SELECT top(100) *  
    FROM CustomerAmericas
)
```

is that this creates a windowed data set that will reside in the RAM and on larger data sets this solution will create severe performance issues as it must first create the partition and then it will use the partition to write to the temp table.

A better solution would be the following:

```
SELECT top(100)* into #tmpFerdeen
FROM Customers

Insert into #tmpFerdeen
SELECT top(100)* 
FROM CustomerEurope

Insert into #tmpFerdeen
SELECT top(100)* 
FROM CustomerAsia

Insert into #tmpFerdeen
SELECT top(100)* 
FROM CustomerAmericas
```

to select insert into the temp table and then add additional rows. However the draw back here is if there are any duplicate rows in the data.

The Best Solution would be the following:

```
Insert into #tmpFerdeen
SELECT top(100)* 
FROM Customers
UNION
SELECT top(100)* 
FROM CustomerEurope
UNION
SELECT top(100)* 
FROM CustomerAsia
UNION
SELECT top(100)* 
FROM CustomerAmericas
```

This method should work for all purposes that require distinct rows. If, however, you want the duplicate rows simply swap out the UNION for UNION ALL

Best of luck!

Comment: Please note that Using `UNION` to get a distinct list will "SORT" your result set.  If you require it to be in order of the statements use `UNION ALL`

Comment: I've no idea what you mean by "windowed data set". This query doesn't use any "window functions" - as you are using `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` you may get a blocking operator in the plan that removes duplicates (by sorting or hashing) but this is the same for your final query. Having it in a derived table doesn't make things worse. Also the requirement was `SELECT ... INTO` to create a new table. Not `INSERT .. SELECT` to an existing one

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this?

```
SELECT * INTO tmpFerdeen (
SELECT top(100)* 
FROM Customers
UNION All
SELECT top(100)* 
FROM CustomerEurope
UNION All
SELECT top(100)* 
FROM CustomerAsia
UNION All
SELECT top(100)* 
FROM CustomerAmericas)
```

Comment: Missing the required table alias (and if added will be the same as the accepted answer)

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this:  Create the final object table, tmpFerdeen with the structure of the union.

Then

```
INSERT INTO tmpFerdeen (
SELECT top(100)* 
FROM Customers
UNION All
SELECT top(100)* 
FROM CustomerEurope
UNION All
SELECT top(100)* 
FROM CustomerAsia
UNION All
SELECT top(100)* 
FROM CustomerAmericas
)
```

Comment: In SQL Server temp tables are created on the fly.  I would like to do this without creating a final object table. Thanks.