# I want to insert the data in temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert the result set of this query into a temporary table inside my stored procedure.

```
select * from A
union all 
select * from B
union all 
select * from C
```

Comment: Does the #temp table already exist? Did you try **anything**?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT *
INTO #SomeTempTable
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM A
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT * 
      FROM B
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT *
      FROM C) D
```

Comment: The derived table [isn't actually needed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591382/is-it-possible-to-use-the-select-into-clause-with-union-all/12619230#12619230)

Comment: @MartinSmith - Thanks, learned something new :)

Answer (score 2):

Please try following:

```
Insert Into #Temp
select * from A
union all 
select * from B
union all 
select * from C
```

Comment: This assumes `#Temp` exists, it requires creating it.

Comment: As the user is asking how to insert data into temporary table but not how to create and insert data into temporary table.